# Why does the rendering twice in react.js

Tags: reactjs

Why does the rendering occur twice in this code?

I  tried to remove the <React.StrictMode></React.StrictMode>

but I can't fixed the re-rendering

I don't think it's a "useState" issue

```
 const [memberArray, setMemberArray] = useState<any[]>([]);
 const [memberArea, setMemberArea] = useState(0);

 console.log("memberArea: " + memberArea);

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const res: any = await axios.get(
        `api/v1/member?memberCode=${memberNum}`
      );
      const data: any = res.data.data.memberList;
      setMemberArray([...data]);
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [memberArea]);
```

Comment: useEffect runs at least once, then it executes getData() getData will then update memberArea causing your useEffect to run once more since it's in your dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

Your effect has one dependecy, `memeberArea`, meaning it will execute effect each time `memberArea` changes. Problem with you approach is because your effect depends on something which is updated by effect itself, without any safe condition to avoid infinity loop or unnecessary state updates.

First time element renders when mounted. Then you step into useEffect and update state inside effect, thus forcing additional, second, rerender, because `memberArea` changed by effect. Problem with your code are not rerenders, but the fact that you will end up with another effect execution because `memberArea` changed in first call and this will lead you to one extra call of `getData`, so you end up with 2 rerenders(which is fine) and 2 subsequent api calls(which is wrong because you will update state with same value twice). Special case is your `memberArray` that, with the current solution, will be updated twice, and since it is array(complex type) you will override reference twice thus forcing jsx part that consumes `memberArray` to rerender 3 times(initially, on first and on second api call).

If you want to call `getData` only once and prevent this side effect you should remove dependency and leave empty array, thus forcing effect to be executed only once, otherwise you would need to insert some checks inside effect to prevent unnecessary state updates like you do now.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation but I don't know how to fix this. If the dependency is removed, the function does not work

Comment: What is `memberNum` inside your function, is it from inner state or props? Does it have stable value or you need to wait for value to resolve?

Comment: I think I solved this problem. Thank you!